# PDO foreach echoing the same value

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

Hi I'm using PDO to connect to a database and I have a class which has a function to see the results of a query, in a table I have the same names Juan and Pedro but when i print them using the foreach loop I get Juan printed 7 times

```
class Posts extends Connection{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function get_result(){
        $res=self::$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM POSTS");
        $res->execute();
        $array=$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($array as $value){
            echo $array['AUTHOR'] . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `print_r($array)`.

Comment: you want to use `fetchAll`. `fetch` only gets one row. And this row will have 7 columns, so you loop through those columns, but echo out only one specific column.

Comment: @u_mulder I have tried print_r that dows almost the same as var_dump It can't help me figure out how I can solve the problem

Comment: @Jeff I tried fetchAll but i had no luck with it :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `PDOStatement::fetch()`, which will only get one (the first, next) row.
So you iterated over one row, which gave you 7 turnes (because you obviously have 7 columns) the same result for `$array['AUTHOR']`.

As you want the whole result set you need to use `fetchAll()`.
This will return an array of all rows, that you then can iterate over.

```
public function get_result(){
    $res=self::$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM POSTS");
    $res->execute();
    $array=$res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($array as $row){
        echo $row['AUTHOR'] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked as i needed it to. I was trying to directly do this:                             foreach($array=$res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
        echo $row['AUTHOR'] . "<br>";
}                                                                                                                 I don't know why it doesn't work as i tried but you helped me a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the problem

```
public function get_result(){
    $res=self::$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM POSTS");
    $res->execute();
    $array = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // $array has fields for ONE fetched row.

    // here you iterate over fields of ONE fetched row
    // and echo one field `AUTHOR`
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        echo $array['AUTHOR'] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

**Solution** - rows must be fetched in a loop, usually it's a `while` loop:

```
public function get_result(){
    $res=self::$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM POSTS");
    $res->execute();

    // here your fetch every row of a result set
    while ($array = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $array['AUTHOR'] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew how to do that sir but I was strictly trying to do it using a foreach loop, thanks anyway.